# Converting decimal in Excel file into money C#

Tags: c#

I have created a console application for reading an Excel file and creating a new record in Microsoft CRM. This program works perfectly on my laptop. But when I move the program into our production server, it doesn't read the value like it should.

This my code:

```
 Selling = row["Column5"].ToString();

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Selling))
 {
     Decimal total_selling = 
     Convert.ToDecimal(Selling,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     sales_contract["new_actualsalesvalue"] = new Money(total_selling);
 }
 else
 {
     sales_contract["new_actualsalesvalue"] = null;
 }
```

Example:

Decimal value 7,098.44

When the program runs from my laptop, within CRM it shows : $7,098.44

But when the program runs from production server, its shows : $709,844.00

I don't think the problem comes from my code, but something missing in my production server. I know this question may not placed in this forum, but could you tell the solution for this...

Comment: Your program needs to take in to account that the decimal separator when it is running on the production server might be different as your laptop. This problem might also appear with Date formats, number formats, etc..

Comment: You're parsing the data as culture invariant, but are they really? I'm not sure, but I think Excel uses local culture, not invariant.

Comment: @raven hi, thanks for the suggestion. It's done by changing the date format and decimal separator through control panel. Could you give your answer below, i will remark it as the answer for this question